# Question about Sylow subgroups of the symmetric group.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Probably an elementary question, but I don't get it, so:

From wikipedia: "The Sylow p-subgroups of the symmetric group of degree $p$ are just the cyclic subgroups genereated by $p$-cycles. There are $(p-1)!/(p-1) = (p-2)!$ such subgroups."

I get that there are $(p-1)!$ $p$-cycles and that there are $(p-1)$ different elements of order $p$ in G, the"supgroup", of the Sylow p-subgroups.
But I don't understand why # of subgroups = $\frac{\# of-p-cycles}{\#of-generators-of-G}$

Comment: p must be a prime number for this to hold. In that case, a subgroup of order $p$ is generated by $p-1$ elements. Namely, if $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$ then apart from identity all the other elements of $H$ generate $H$.